# C# typeof("Object Variable get type")

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class that has a property of type object that will get the value of an Entity Framework table.

Here is the properties of the class:

```
public string EntityName
{
   get { return _entityName; }
   set { _entityName = value; }
}
private string _entityName;

public object EntityType
{
   get { return _entityType; }
   set { _entityType = value; }
}
private object _entityType;
```

The object can be any table, depends on when it was initialized.
Next I want all the column names of the table in the object.
Here is the code that should give it to me:

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> ReadColumnNames()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> names = typeof("Problem Here").GetProperties()
                    .Select(property => property.Name)
                    .ToList();

        ObservableCollection<string> observableNames = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        foreach (string name in names)
        {
            observableNames.Add(name);
        }

        return observableNames;
    }
```

Problem is that the typeof() method requires a type and the type can be of any table. If I create a variable of Type i.e. 
Type myType = EntityDetail.GetType()
the typeof() denies it because it is a variable and not a type.

Any suggestions on what I can do?

I don't know if there is a better way to do this, if there is feel free to share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose you need `myEntity.GetType` instead of `typeof(...)` which will return the *runtime*-type of your entity.

Comment: So why can't you use `EntityDetail.GetType()` as you already have found? Your problem statement is unclear to me.

Comment: why you couldn't use EntityDetail.GetType().GetProperties() etc...  ?

Comment: What is `EntityDetail`? The name of a class or the name of an instance of a class?

Comment: EntityDetail is the name of the class yes. @HimBromBeere

Comment: And why can´t you use `typeof(EntityDetail)` in this case? Or is ÈntityDetail` just one possible type of the property `EntityType`? Your question is quite unclear, no-one knows how your teyps and properties rely to each other.

Comment: Basically the code I posted is the whole class without the constructor which sets the properties EntityType and EntityName. typeof(EntityDetail) doesn't work because then it doesn't recognize the .Select() sub property. @HimBromBeere

Comment: But you have `using System.Linq`, don´t you?

Comment: Thanks I didn't have that reference and if fixed the problem. How do I accept you comment as the answer? @HimBromBeere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This maybe?

```
IEnumerable<string> names = typeof(EntityDetail).GetProperties()
    .Select(property => property.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Note that this requires a `using System.Linq`.

`typeof` will expect a *compile*-time type. If you don´t know the actuaö type at compile-time, use `myInstance.GetType()` instead of `typeof(...)` instead.

Comment: I have tried it but the the .Select is not recognized as a property. Well not on EntityDetail since it is the class name but on the property variable EntityType.

Comment: using System.Linq; was what I was missing.